# Standalone GWT Deployment

Tags: gwt, web-deployment

So, this is a pretty trivial thing to accomplish apparently, but for some reason it just will not work for me. I created a VERY SIMPLE GWT app. It uses UIBinder just to display a label and a button, no actual processing or handling takes place. I did this to test deploying the app using strictly JS and html that is not hosted by Eclipse and Jetty or whatever.

I compile my app, run it in eclipse, and it works fine. However, when I try to run the html page directly from the WAR directory, it does not work.

Do I need this running on a webserver for it to work? It is just html and js, so I shouldn't? I've been to the GWT site about deploying, and surfed quite a few forums. They seem to always mention the necessity of a server, but it seems like it should not be necessary?

Comment: Post your host page HTML and main module .gwt.xml file.

Comment: Ditto @Strelok. You likely are need to do a GWT Compile and make sure you are poinging to the right nocache.js

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a pure JavaScript and HTML it should work properly without server. Checkout this link: [Compile and run in Production Mode with Eclipse](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html#compiling)

Comment: yeah, that it what I have been trying, and it only shows the static HTML, not the GWT generated code.

Answer (score 0):

In your EntryPoint class, in onModuleLoad() there's a `RootPanel.get("someDivId")` call somewhere. Make sure your html page (=the host page) contains a div with that id.

Also make sure your host page calls the right java script file. It's easy to forget to edit the host page after you renamed your GWT module (see rename-to in your .gwt.xml), as the generated JavaScript file matches your module name.

Comment: thanks, I tried everything you guys said - turns out its a Chrome bug............Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///E:/Program%20Files/eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64/Workspace/MyTest/war/index.html from frame with URL file:///E:/Program%20Files/eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64/Workspace/MyTest/war/index/F57AEF245E97FF90931EDDEEAD18F569.cache.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.........It works fine in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This will work locally on all browsers except Chrome for security reasons.
See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31068
and http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70088